# Woocommerce Ajax Add cart not working

Tags: ajax, javascript, woocommerce-offtopic, cookies

In woocommerce ajax add to cart method not adding when cart is empty, if cart contains something then my ajax function adds but if cart is empty it doesn't add. And no error.

Here is the [link](http://izi-dev.fr/forreygalland/product/macaroons).
PHP add cart function:

```
function add_custom_product_meta() {
    global $woocommerce, $wpdb;

    $item_id = isset($_POST['item_id']) ? apply_filters( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_product_id', absint( $_POST['item_id'] ) ) : FALSE;
    $quantity = empty( $_POST['quantity'] ) ? 1 : wc_stock_amount( $_POST['quantity'] );
    $passed_validation = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', true, $item_id, $quantity );
    $product_status    = get_post_status( $item_id );

    $variation_id = isset($_POST['variation_id']) ? $_POST['variation_id'] : 0;
    $atributes = isset($_POST['atributes']) ? $_POST['atributes'] : 'Small';
    $attribute_pa_macaroons = isset($_POST['attribute_pa_macaroons']) ? $_POST['attribute_pa_macaroons'] : FALSE;

    if($attribute_pa_macaroons && $passed_validation && $woocommerce->cart->add_to_cart( $item_id, $quantity, $variation_id, array( 'attribute_size' => $atributes,  "macaroons" => $attribute_pa_macaroons))){

        //$added = $woocommerce->cart->add_to_cart( $item_id, $quantity, $variation_id, array( 'attribute_size' => $atributes,  "macaroons" => $attribute_pa_macaroons));

        do_action( 'woocommerce_ajax_added_to_cart', $item_id );

        if ( get_option( 'woocommerce_cart_redirect_after_add' ) == 'yes' ) {
            wc_add_to_cart_message( $item_id );
        }

        WC_AJAX::get_refreshed_fragments();

        echo json_encode(array(
            'atributes' => $atributes,
            'macaroons' => $attribute_pa_macaroons,
            'product_added' => TRUE,
            'ajax_complete' => TRUE,
            'posted' => isset($_POST['item_id']) ? $woocommerce->cart : 'item_id is empty'
        ));
        wp_die();
    }

    echo json_encode(array(
        'product_id' => FALSE,
        'product_added' => FALSE,
        'ajax_complete' => TRUE,
        'posted' => $attribute_pa_macaroons
    ));
    wp_die();
}
```

Javascript Ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
                        type : 'post',
                        dataType : 'json',
                        url : woocommerce_params.ajax_url,
                        data : {
                            'action' : 'elephas_addtocart_box',
                            'item_id' : itemID,
                            'quantity' : quantity,
                            'variation_id' : variathionID,
                            'atributes' : atributes,
                            'attribute_pa_macaroons' : itemData
                        }
                    })
                    .done(function(response){
                        if(response.ajax_complete){
                            document.location.reload(true);
                        }
                    })
                    .error(function(error){
                        console.log(error);
                    })
                    .always(function(response){
                        if(response.ajax_complete){
                            document.location.reload(true);
                        }
                    });
```

Comment: Your link is local.

Comment: sorry :) http://izi-dev.fr/forreygalland/product/macaroons/

Comment: I'm guessing you need to add enough "Macaroons" until you fill the box (8|16|32) in order to unlock the **Add to cart** button. I'm also guessing you are not exactly familiar with the website yet? Funniest "error" today, by far!

Comment: Its not about filling the box, please try with emty cart and emty all cookies on your browser then its difficult to add macaroon as product, but other products can be add simply.

Comment: You are on a customizable product page. You cannot buy an empty box of Macaroons. You have to specify what macaroons you want inside. Select "Small" box, press the **+** button from any macaroons until box is full and you can order. The script responsible for this is in plugins/woocommerce/assets/js/frontend. Unfortunatelly they're all minified.

Comment: Please clear the cookies of that website and try to add macaroon box to your cart. FYI i know that you have to fill the box with macaroons to activate the button and its not the question. Question is why its not adding the product to shopping cart when cart is empty.

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce your bug. It's working perfectly for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your php add_to_cart function not setting cart cookies, you can do this manually by adding this line inside the if condition before

```
//$added
```

line

add this line

```
do_action( 'woocommerce_set_cart_cookies', TRUE );
```

this will set cart cookies.

Comment: Yes its working now.

Comment: thank you!! Fixed my empty cart for guest users, which stopped working after a WC 3.0 update